# Help using vector quantization

Tags: matlab, speech-recognition, mfcc, quantization

I have a sample signal, and I computed MFCC using this [code](http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/voicebox/doc/voicebox/melcepst.html).Now I have an array of 1225x12 size, where there are 12 coefficients for 1225 frames. Now I want to test another signal against this sample, and use vector quantization for this.I have this [code](http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/voicebox/doc/voicebox/kmeanlbg.html), but cannot quite understand what to do. It takes data vectors as input,but I have a matrics. Do I convert it into a vector in some way? And how do I determine if two arrays match?

Comment: Vector quantization is irrelevant here, you need to read your task again, it meant something different.

Answer (score 0):

From your reference :
Inputs:
 D contains data vectors (one per row)
...
Outputs 
J indicates which centre each data vector belongs to

You need to have 12 coefficients in each row of your input matrix. In J you will have a number from 1 to K indicating the cluster number. The number of rows in J will be as in D.
You can use cell2mat and reshape if you need.
I just not sure that clustering in such high dimensions make sense. It may worth making PCA first.